# How to define and use other color spaces not included in the ColorSpace options?

Tags: color

I'm specifically interested in YCbCr and Munsell color spaces which are not included in the ColorSpace options.

Is there any way to define these color spaces in Mathematica and use them like other color spaces?

My intention is to visualize the corresponding gamut and find equidistant colors in the gamut with their corresponding color values.

[N.B. - I know the conversion formula, but it is not a conversion problem. I want to use these color spaces as primary color spaces and not derived from other color spaces.]

Comment: Probably [MunsellAndKubelkaMunkToolboxFeb2017](http://www.munsellcolourscienceforpainters.com/MunsellAndKubelkaMunkToolbox/MunsellAndKubelkaMunkToolbox.html) is a good starting point for implementing Munsell color space.

Comment: Also, *Mathematica* is bundled with a `RLink` and [there is a package `munsell` for R which allows to work entirely in the Munsell colourspace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36942038/590388).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov : I haven't found any such package in Mathematica, although it has a guide on RLink. Can you please provide me with some mathematica references?

Comment: I don't know such a package for *Mathematica*. But as I said there are RLink and MatLink (for MatLab). So you can use them or translate MatLab code to WL.